How can I write equivalent libcurl code for a curl command with -d option and -X PUT option?
I'm tring to implement payhip Software License Keys usage API.
I've succeeded in issuing the following curl command;
curl https://payhip.com/api/v1/license/usage -d "product_link=MY_PRODUCT" -d "license_key=MY_KEY" -X PUT --header "payhip-api-key: API_KEY_HERE"

Then, I'm writing production code in c with libcurl library as follows;
   // curl
    CURL *curl = curl_easy_init();
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://payhip.com/api/v1/license/usage");
    struct curl_slist *list = NULL;
    list = curl_slist_append(list, "API_KEY_HERE");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, list);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "product_link=MY_PRODUCT");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "license_key=MY_KEY");
    CURLcode res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

The curl_easy_perform(curl) returned 0, but the response was HTTP/2 400  and the response body said
{"code":"required_parameters","message":"Missing or empty required parameters","success":false}

How can I write collect put parameters in curl_easy_setopt()?

Even if you were doing a POST, that's not how one uses POSTFIELDS. It expects you to provide the body of the request, meaning the document to POST. It's up to you to build the document to send, whether it's a application/x-www-form-urlencoded document or not.

Same for PUT. You need to build the document to send yourself. For PUT requests, you can use the READFUNCTION mechanism to provide the document instead of POSTFIELDS.

I don't believe that libcurl provides any tools to help build a application/x-www-form-urlencoded document (though it does provide the means of building a multipart/form-data document through curl_mime_init et al).

Doesn't curl have an option to generate the C code equivalent to a given set of command line options?

I've found the solution as follows:
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,"product_link=MY_PRODUCT&license_key=MY_KEY");
// curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "product_link=MY_PRODUCT");
// curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "license_key=MY_KEY");

This answer is so informative for this question as well.
